# Bootstrap class does not seem to have any effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I got the ownership of a web app which is a mix of bootstrap(5) and html code.
The problem is if I try to push a column using `col-md-offset-4` it does not work at all.

it's not just col-md-offset-4, any col-md-offset-* is not working.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what environment are you trying to run this code? Are you using bootstrap 5 for this or it is other version?

Comment: in VS code. I'm using bootstrap 5 libraries,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is slightly different: See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#offset-classes) the syntax is `class="col-md-4 offset-md-4"`

```css
[class*=col-] {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">.col</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">.col-md-6 .offset-md-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```